# How come Lambda Calculus is a calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do Algebra and Calculus mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54763/what-do-algebra-and-calculus-mean)

Where are the numbers? derivatives? integrals? limits?
If I understand it correctly, lambda calculus is all about symbols. There are no numbers or operators like addition or multiplications except in a very abstract way like Church encoding and alike. The way I see it, it has nothing to do with what we called calculus in high school or university. Insights?

Comment: It's a "calculus" in the sense of a system of manipulations (like "logical calculus"), not a "calculus" in the sense of "differential calculus" that you're thinking of.

Comment: If compact Hausdorff spaces are normal, how come $\beta\mathbb N$ is so crazy? :-) Names are just words.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do Algebra and Calculus mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54763/what-do-algebra-and-calculus-mean) or [What does “calculus” mean in the most general sense?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185559/what-does-calculus-mean-in-the-most-general-sense) or [what is meant if someone writes “calculus of ..”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127078/terminology-what-is-meant-if-someone-writes-calculus-of)

Answer (score 9):

Calculus is here what would be called *Kalkül* in German or *calcul* in French, coming from latin *calculus* "stone (used for computation)" and denotes a formal system of rules. Thus *lambda calculus* is not the same as calculus in the sense of *differential and integral calculus* (which e.g. in German is called *Differential- und Integralrechnung*, not *Differential- und Integralkalkül*)