# What does "calculus" mean?

Tags: calculus, logic, terminology, lambda-calculus, formal-systems

1. "calculus" and "formal system"

   From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Terminology

   > a calculus is a formal system that consists of
   >
   > - a set of syntactic expressions (well-formed formulæ or wffs),
   > - a distinguished subset of these expressions (axioms), plus
   > - a set of formal rules that define a specific binary relation on the space of expressions.

   From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system

   > Formal systems in mathematics consist of the following elements:
   >
   > - A finite set of symbols (i.e. the alphabet), that can be used for constructing formulas (i.e. finite strings of symbols).
   > - A grammar, which tells how well-formed formulas (abbreviated wff) are constructed out of the symbols in the alphabet. It is
   >     usually
   >     required that there be a decision procedure for deciding whether a
   >     formula is well formed or not.
   > - A set of axioms or axiom schemata: each axiom must be a wff.
   > - A set of inference rules.

   what is the difference between a formal system, and a calculus,
   then? I think they are the same?
2. "calculus" and "logic system"

   "Calculus" appears in "propositional calculus" and "first-order
   predicate calculus", which are also called "propositional logic" and
   "first-order logic" respectively. So I thought "calculus" and
   "logic" mean the same, and "a logic" is, according to
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system#Logical_system,

   > A logical system or, for short, logic, is a formal system together with a form of semantics, usually in the form of model-theoretic
   >   interpretation, which assigns truth values to sentences of the
   >   formal language, that is, formulae that contain no free variables.

   But then I saw "calculus" also appears in "lambda calculus", which
   is also a formal system. I think a lambda calculus isn't a logic
   system, right? What does "calculus" mean in "lambda calculus"?
3. Furthermore  "calculus" can also mean computational real analysis for first-year college students.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually calculus means stone. See Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: It's also that stuff on your teeth.

Comment: Stones, in the sense of abacus were used in calculation, it also refers to a medical condition of having a calcified solid in the organs or ducts, I think its quite painful.

Comment: @Arkamis: you mean "plaque"?

Comment: No, I mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_(dental)

Comment: It's original meaning comes from the notion of "stone counting", the idea of using small stones to tally some quantity. In a sense, with small stones (e.g. pebbles), the notion of calculus can be extrapolated to the idea of examining behavior as one adds or removes stones.

Comment: These terms are fairly subjective.  I consider a formal system to be a fully specified logic down to the finest detail (precise enough to be a computer program).  I consider a calculus to be primitive mechanical operations of a logic, such as replacing expressions, introducing assumptions, and so forth.  In other contexts, calculus just means "a set of rules for manipulation", such as the calculus of differentials.

Comment: A calculus consists of a means of computing formulas.

Comment: So did these comments and answers help? I have had the same question for many years and my personal current answer is that it is a term rewriting system that may or may not result in a normal form. When it does result in a normal form I think that it should have a different name other than calculus because there is a big difference between being able to have a normal form and not having a normal form.

Comment: be back later. @GuyCoder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do Algebra and Calculus mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54763/what-do-algebra-and-calculus-mean)

Answer (score 4):

Following my answer to your previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873183/are-variables-logical-or-non-logical-symbols-in-a-logic-system), we can say that a *formal system* is made by an *alphabet* (the set of symbols), a *gramamr* (the formation rules, defining the "correct" expressions, i.e. the set of *well-formed formulas*) and a *proof system* or *deductive calculus*.

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA110) (2nd ed - 2001), page 110 :

> We will introduce formal proofs but we will call them *deductions*, to avoid confusion
>   with our English-language proofs.
>
> We will [...] select an infinite set $\Lambda$ of formulas to be called *logical axioms*. And we will have a *rule of inference* [i.e. *modus ponens*], which will enable us to obtain a new formula from certain others. Then for a set $\Gamma$ of formulas, the *theorems* of $\Gamma$ will be the formulas which can be obtained from $\Gamma \cup \Lambda$ by use of the rule of inference (some finite number of times).
>
> If $\varphi$ is a theorem of $\Gamma$ (written $\vdash \varphi$), then a sequence of formulas that records (as explained below) how $\varphi$ was obtained from $\Gamma \cup \Lambda$ with the rule of inference will be called a deduction of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$.
>
> The choice of $\Lambda$ and the choice of the rule (or rules) of inference are far from unique. In this [book] we are presenting one *deductive calculus* for *first-order logic*, chosen from the array of possible calculi. (For example, one can have $\Gamma = \emptyset$ by using many rules of inference [i.e. *Natural Deduction*]. We will take the opposite extreme; our set $\Lambda$ will be infinite but we will have only one rule of inference.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816481/what-differences-and-relation-are-between-proof-systems-and-deductive-systems#comment7869612_3816481

Comment: Please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816481/what-differences-and-relation-are-between-proof-systems-and-deductive-systems#comment7871290_3816481