# What is the difference between a calculus and an algebra?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, terminology, algebras

You can have a lambda *calculus*, the *calculus* of the real numbers or a logical *calculus* but on the other hand you could also have an *algebra* of sets, a Lie *algebra*, or a linear *algebra*.

Is there any convention which dictates whether something is an *algebra* or a *calculus*?

From my understanding, a *calculus* seems to give you information about objects you might encounter within a space, while an *algebra* gives you information about the interactions and structure within the space as a whole. Is this correct?

Comment: Calculus is kind of a catch-all term and in days of old, *calculus* meant any procedure by which things were calculated (loosely speaking). Algebra is also a bit liberally used in mathematics, but when one comes across the word algebra, one should think about some sort of operations on sets, i.e. algebras of sets, algebras over fields, etc.

Comment: The question is about difference, rather than meaning. What I'm unclear about is: Under what viewpoints can one be seen as a sub-set of the other? What do these different *things* allow you to do that the other won't. e.g. if calculus is just a procedure, does expanding it to an algebra (implied super-set) then allow proofs about the calculation's applicability?, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A calculus is a system of rules for manipulating symbols and expressions. An algebra is a set with operations that can be preformed on its elements.

Comment: I am wondering how "rules" are actually different from "operations that can be preformed".